# How to increase space between dotted border dots and write between them

Tags: html, css

I am using dotted style border in my box like

```
 body {
  background-color: black;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 10%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 1px 10px; 
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

How can I write between dots?

Example image:

[image: example image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to increase space between the dots - could you just write over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way which doesn't require a 'gap' in the dots - we just write on top of them (with a black background and a bit of padding depending on what you want).

Without more info on exactly what is required in terms of spacing of the text it is not possible to be more specific but this layout using rotated text and different elements for each 'chunk' of text hopefully gives you a start.

```css
 body {
  background-color: black;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 10%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 1px 10px; 
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.text:nth-child(1) {
  top: 90%;
}
.text:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="text">some text</div>
<div class="text">and some more</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lawd CSS is *such* a mess